# React Native: KeyboardAvoidingView only works for Android API >= 30

Tags: android, react-native

KeyboardAvoidingView works fine on Android API > 29, but it does not work at all on API < 30. I have tested the same app on the same emulator with API 28, 29, 30 and 33. Does anybody have explanation for that?

I know that I can achieve similar result what KeyboardAvoidingView does with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, but I specifically do not want to use it. So I have set it to `"adjustNothing"`.